# CakePHP 2.2.3 set_error_handler() expects the argument (ErrorHandler::handleError)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

After uploading files i get this issue which is comeing from cakes core and don´t know what to do to solve it?

```
Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (ErrorHandler::handleError) to be a valid callback in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The Errorhandler file wasn´t uploaded. There was my be some errors by uploading.